# Would a new human-like general artificial intelligence be more similar, in terms of eduction, to a toddler or an adult human?

Tags: philosophy, agi, human-like

The naive concept of a general AI, or strong AI, or artificial general intelligence, is some kind of software that can answer questions like

> What is the volume of a cube that is 1 m wide?

or even

> Why are there only two political parties in the US?

The second question requires external knowledge and high-level reasoning. For example that US means USA in the context, the constitution and that having two parties is caused by the mathematical properties of the election system.

But I would expect that newborn human child is intelligent in the sense of intelligence that is used in general artificial intelligence, but toddlers can not answer these questions.

That is not because an infant is not intelligent, but because it is not educated, I think.

What is the apparent level of education of an artificial intelligence that could be called human-like?

Answer (score 1):

A human-level AI should be able to learn and behave in the same way that humans learn and behave, otherwise, we shouldn't be calling it a human-level AI. So, either if it starts with more or less knowledge of a baby human, it should be able to learn similarly to a human and acquire more knowledge with experience.

> What is the apparent level of education of an artificial intelligence that could be called human-like?

To answer you question more directly, the level of education of a human-like AI (even newly created ones) can potentially be variable (i.e. different human-like AIs could potentially have different levels of education), but the human-like AI will necessarily need to be able to increase its level of education and, in general, knowledge (because humans can also do this).

Moreover, note that [AGI is not necessarily restricted to human-level AI](https://content.sciendo.com/view/journals/jagi/5/1/article-p1.xml). So, other AGIs may not follow the same principles of humans.